# How to join sheet1 and sheet2 data based on key using Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to change the code below to be related between Sheets

```
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.page || 1;
  var limit = e.parameter.limit || 10;
  var search = e.parameter.search || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=12237511399");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search);
}

function getUsers(sheet, page, limit, search){
  var lowCase = search.toString().toLowerCase();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().filter(([,,c]) => c.toString().toLowerCase().includes(lowCase));
  var dataArray = rows.splice(limit * (page - 1), limit).reduce((ar, [a, b, c, d]) => ar.concat({id: a, year: b, title: c, img: d}), []);
  var jo = {};
  jo.user = dataArray;
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

The following is an example that is slightly similar because there is a relation **EmployeeID** on **Employee** and **Address**.

[image: example]

I want how to make **id** in Sheets **list_film** relate to **id_film** in Sheets **list_review** and produce combined data output like this

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "year": "2019",
    "titles": "The Aeronauts",
    "img": "null",
    "id_review": "1",
    "id_film": "1",
    "review": "It's an eye opener movie for the youngsters who are on the path of terrorism for the greed of fake Hoors."
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "year": "2019",
    "titles": "Bluebird",
    "img": "null",
    "id_review": "2",
    "id_film": "2",
    "review": "What is thought provoking in this movie?"
  }
]
```

This is the Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=12237511399

Comment: the link you have provided cannot be accessed, please make it public.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for my bad and confusing english, I've edited it and provided pictures

Comment: @Twilight Sorry, I've unlocked the permissions now

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected values using your sample input values, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize. At that time, when you provide your expected value, I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your updated question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  const [sheet1Head, ...sheet1Values] = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  const [sheet2Head, ...sheet2Values] = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  const sheet1Obj = sheet1Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet1Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.uid_buyer] = e, o), {});
  const sheet2Obj = sheet2Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet2Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.uid_buyer] = e, o), {});

  const res1 = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, { ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }]));
  console.log(res1);

  const res2 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: { ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) } }));
  console.log(res2);

  const res3 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }));
  console.log(res3);
}
```

- Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your expected values from your sample input values. So, I proposed the results of 3 patterns.
- When this script is run, `res1`, `res2`, and `res3` are as follows.

  - `res1`

    ```json
    {
      "101010":{"id_order":123111,"name_product":"Nano module","uid_buyer":101010,"desc":"Nano module is nano module","name":"john","address":"Abc Street, 13","phone":90909},
      "121212":{"id_order":111000,"name_product":"Micro RC","uid_buyer":121212,"desc":"Receiver","name":"melisa","address":"Bca Street, 12","phone":90909}
    }
    ```
  - `res2`

    ```json
    [
      {"101010":{"id_order":123111,"name_product":"Nano module","uid_buyer":101010,"desc":"Nano module is nano module","name":"john","address":"Abc Street, 13","phone":90909}},
      {"121212":{"id_order":111000,"name_product":"Micro RC","uid_buyer":121212,"desc":"Receiver","name":"melisa","address":"Bca Street, 12","phone":90909}}
    ]
    ```
  - `res3`

    ```json
    [
      {"id_order":123111,"name_product":"Nano module","uid_buyer":101010,"desc":"Nano module is nano module","name":"john","address":"Abc Street, 13","phone":90909},
      {"id_order":111000,"name_product":"Micro RC","uid_buyer":121212,"desc":"Receiver","name":"melisa","address":"Bca Street, 12","phone":90909}
    ]
    ```

#### Note:

- This script is for your provided Spreadsheet. So, if you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added:

When I saw your updated question, I was surprised that your question has already been largely changed from your initial question. About your new question, how about the following modified script? In this modification, I used the above script in my answer.

When you use this script as Web Apps, please reflect the latest script to the Web Apps. Please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("list_review");
  const [sheet1Head, ...sheet1Values] = sheet1.getRange("A1:D" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const [sheet2Head, ...sheet2Values] = sheet2.getRange("A1:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sheet1Obj = sheet1Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet1Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e, o), {});
  const sheet2Obj = sheet2Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet2Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id_film] = e, o), {});
  let res3 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }));
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    const { limit = 0 } = e.parameter;
    if (limit > 0) {
      res3 = res3.splice(0, limit)
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res3)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- When this script is run as the Web Apps with no query parameter, the following result is obtained.

  ```
  [
    {"id_review":1,"id_film":1,"review":"It's an eye opener movie for the youngsters who are on the path of terrorism for the greed of fake Hoors.\r\n\r","id":1,"year":2019,"titles":"The Aeronauts","img":"null"},
    {"id_review":2,"id_film":2,"review":"What is thought provoking in this movie? ","id":2,"year":2019,"titles":"Bluebird","img":"null"}
  ]
  ```
- About `It's just that I need to display all existing data and then limit the data with the command at the end ?limit=10`, do you want to control the length of output array length? Unfortunately, I couldn't find about the detail of this additional request in your new question. So, this is just my guess. When my understanding of your new request is correct, when the above Web Apps is requested by `https://script.google.com/macros/s/{deploymentId}/exec?limit=10`, 10 items are returned.
- **This script is for your updated provided Spreadsheet. When you change the Spreadsheet again, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.**

Comment: Sorry if my question is confusing, I've fixed mine

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. First, from your added value, I could know that you wanted an array including objects. But, I have to apologize that I cannot understand your expected result. In your showing expected value, the keys of "id","year","titles":,"img","id_review","id_film","review" are used. But, when I saw your provided Spreadsheet, I cannot find those values. In this case, I have to know the detailed logic for retrieving your expected value. Can I ask you about the detail of it? By this, I would like to modify my sample script.

Comment: @T6VK For example, when you want an array including objects, how about `res3` in my sample? But, if that was not your expected result, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the sample input values and the sample output values using the sample input values? By this, I would like to modify the script. I deeply apologize that I cannot resolve your question soon.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed my Sheets page. Thank you for your response.

Comment: it looks like res3 is the relevant one for my output example in the question. It's just that I need to display all existing data and then limit the data with the command at the end ?limit=10

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. First, I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. When I saw your updated question, I was surprised that your question has already been largely changed. I couldn't notice your actual question. I really apologize for this again. For your new question, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your new question, I apologize again.

Comment: your example is good, but what if I want to merge the Sheets again. I still don't understand this part let res3 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }) );

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. About your new question of `but what if I want to merge the Sheets again.`. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. And, you had already largely changed your question.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76679639/how-do-add-limit-and-pagination-while-sorting-the-last-data-to-be-in-the-first-p

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for your response. Now, I saw your new question. And, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer and the discussion.

Comment: @T6VK Thank you for replying. I believe that your new question will be resolved.