# How do add limit and pagination while sorting the last data to be in the first part in Google Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Coming from the previously answered question, I now get the entire data displayed at one time. Maybe for a little data is not problem.

But I'm sure if the data reaches hundreds it will be very burdensome, so I can get a solution for the code below so I can retrieve the last row data to be the first based on the contents of the parameters along with the pagination.

```
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("list_review");
  const [sheet1Head, ...sheet1Values] = sheet1.getRange("A1:D" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const [sheet2Head, ...sheet2Values] = sheet2.getRange("A1:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const sheet1Obj = sheet1Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet1Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e, o), {});
  const sheet2Obj = sheet2Values.map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet2Head[j]] = c, o), {})).reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id_film] = e, o), {});
  let res3 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj).map(([k, v]) => ({ ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }));
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    const { limit = 0 } = e.parameter;
    if (limit > 0) {
      res3 = res3.splice(0, limit)
    }
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(res3)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

for example a parameter as follows:

```
?limit=10&pages=1
```

[image]

then I will get 10 data on page 1 and so on until the end of all existing data and the results of the data starting from the last data row.(reversed)

Sorry for my bad english.

The following is the data on the Spreadsheet that I use:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=0

Comment: So basically, you want to reverse the values to the Google Sheet, so they can go from `2015 The Phoenix Incident ` to `2019 The Aeronauts` instead of  `2019 The Aeronauts` to `2015 The Phoenix Incident `, like reversing the array, but keep the values of the original array where they are, so you can keep adding data? Is that correct?

Comment: @Giselle Valladares Basically I want when the command ?limit=10&pages=1 is executed to be able to divide all existing data only appear a maximum of 10 lines on one page.

Comment: Then the data that appears will start from the last row of data when the script is run. Like when running the sort function.

Comment: @Giselle Valladares Sorry I'm late to understand but what you wrote That's right, I want to display data from last to earliest number not from first to last row

Comment: And keeping the pagination of `10`? So `page 1` will be from the movie ID `112` to `103`, `page 2` will be from `102` to `93`, and so on. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Giselle Valladare That's right, you understand well

Comment: Cool, I think I got the code now. I'm just running some test. I was able to reverse the object, I'm just having issues with the pagination.

Comment: That's what happened to me too, I'm confused how to solve the pagination problem

Comment: I manage to do it, I think.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I will add the first part, to reverse the values and start from the last row. The process is very simple, you need to replace the last part of the code for this:

```
  reverse_array_res3 = res3.reverse()

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(reverse_array_res3))
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

I will keep working on the pagination, since I'm not sure where you are sending the data. I'm working on an example by using Apps Script HTML services for my example.

**Update: **

Here is the information to add the pages, I added the variable `pages_number`, to calculate the number of pages that will be pass to the JSON file. Like this:

```
let pages_number = Math.round(reverse_array_res3.length/10)
```

Here is the complete code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("list_review");
  const [sheet1Head, ...sheet1Values] = sheet1
    .getRange("A1:D" + sheet1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const [sheet2Head, ...sheet2Values] = sheet2
    .getRange("A1:C" + sheet2.getLastRow()).getValues();

  const sheet1Obj = sheet1Values
    .map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet1Head[j]] = c, o), {}))
    .reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id] = e, o), {});
  const sheet2Obj = sheet2Values
    .map(r => r.reduce((o, c, j) => (o[sheet2Head[j]] = c, o), {}))
    .reduce((o, e) => (o[e.id_film] = e, o), {});


  let res3 = Object.entries(sheet2Obj)
    .map(([k, v]) => ({ ...v, ...(sheet1Obj[k] || {}) }));
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    const { limit = 0 } = e.parameter;
    if (limit > 0) {
      res3 = res3.splice(0, limit)

    }
  }
  reverse_array_res3 = res3.reverse()
  let pages_number = Math.round(reverse_array_res3.length / 10)
  return buildSuccessResponse(reverse_array_res3, pages_number)
}


function buildSuccessResponse(data, pages) {
  var output = JSON.stringify({
    data: data,
    pages: pages,
    limit: 10
  });

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(output)
    .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

And you will get the following result:

[image: JSON file 1]

[image: JSON file 2]

Comment: Cool, I got a new lesson

Comment: I didn't know about that feature, either, until I had to deal with this question. I learn something new today too, thanks.

Comment: So how to run pagination and limit commands in url?

Comment: From where are you calling the JSON file? How are you calling the JSON file? What are you using the JSON file for?

Comment: dari url yang diberikan saat membuild di Google Script